# How get values from a bootstrap checkboxes button group?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I'm trying to use [Boostrap buttons checkboxes](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio) plugin. It works good for submitting data, However I would like to get it's values at client using JS (jQuery).

If they are regular input, then I should only read the "checked" parameter.

The expected behavior is to be able to read the "checked" as true or false status from the checkboxes. It works on regular checkboxes.

However the checked status does not changes if you're using the bootstrap plugin..

How can I get the selected checkboxes when the Bootstrap Button plug-in is active?

I'm using Chrome 53 and inspecting my project and the [Bootstrap site](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio) itself with same behaviour

Comment: Just trying to detect which check box has the `active` class is not a difficult task, But will be purely not useful. I suppose you want also to assign a value to each checkbox that you want to retrieve in order to use them somewhere in your application. So you need to use in this case some `jquery` so you can set or unset the checked attribute to the selected check box(es) and then retrieve the values of the checked one(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap checkboxes work by setting another input when selecting the checkbox. You can save yourself some time and just use the `serialize()` function. It should give you what you need in a nice neat array:

```
var data = $('form').serialize();
```

Where `form` is the selector for your form.

Answer (score 1):

> `.serialize()`, encode a set of form elements as a string for submission.

The `.serialize()` method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation. It can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual form controls, such as `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>`: `$( "input, textarea, select" ).serialize();`

Code snippet below selects a `<form>` itself for serialization,

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log( $( this ).serialize() );
});
```

A sample output from serialize function,

```
single=Single&multiple=Multiple3&check=check1&check=check2&radio=radio2
```

Read more about this function and check out the code example at Offical jQuery Doc [here](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).